# Raspberry PI, PHP, MPG123 playing music via 3.5mm jack - No sound via PHP?

Tags: php

Got my PI for xmas and I want to turn it into a web based music player.

As a test I run these commands:
First, make sure it's using the 3.5mm jack:

```
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
```

Then play the music:

```
sudo mpg123 /files/music/Martin_Garrix_Animals.mp3
```

Doing this directly into the console works.

If I try doing it via PHP

```
<?php

//using either of these, tried with sudo before each command
exec("mpg123 ../files/music/Martin_Garrix_Animals.mp3");
shell_exec("mpg123 ../files/music/Martin_Garrix_Animals.mp3");

?>
```

I get nothing, I'm not sure if it's due to permissions?

Any ideas?

Thanks

S

Comment: Try playing a long audio file and see if mpg123 starts using `top`

Comment: Add echo and you'll see the console output when you run your php script.
echo exec("mpg123 ../files/music/Martin_Garrix_Animals.mp3");

Comment: Use `ps aux | grep php` to find out as which user is your PHP running as. Then add this user to `audio` group using `usermod -a -G audio <username>` (substiting <username> with proper user, it will probably be `www-data`). Also try changing relative paths to absolute ones.

Comment: @Dead133 this is the output i get when using shell_exec.jackdmp 1.9.9 Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others. Copyright 2004-2012 Grame. jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10 control device hw:0 control device hw:0

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski the result of that is: pi        2881  0.0  0.1   3544   808 pts/0    S+   11:45   0:00 grep --color=auto php. So i ran "sudo usermod -a -G audio pi" and tried again but same thing. No sound.

Comment: Just a thought: Try using the absolute path

Comment: Checked TOP, it is running as www-data, my bad. Added www-data to audio group too but still doesn't work @Jervelund absoluate path still not working.

Comment: Try writing a shell script that executes `mpg123 /files/music/Martin_Garrix_Animals.mp3` and running that from PHP

Comment: @Jervelund still no luck :(

Comment: You could try redirecting the output of the command run to some file to so what is wrong. Add `>/tmp/log.txt 2>&1` to the end of the line, then inspect `/tmp/log.txt` file.

Comment: That helped... Check this: http://pastebin.com/0r8EHYkE

Comment: There still seems to be some security issues: `Home directory /var/www not ours.` can you try running as root to determine if this is the issue?

Comment: How to run this as root from a php script? Running it via putty console it works fine

Comment: Sudo implies that the user cannot write directly to the audio device.

Comment: Any luck guys ?
Im into the same problem ?! Krzysztof Adamski did you fix the problem ?! If you did, how ?!
Thanks !

Comment: Try using mpg321 rather than mpg123.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem can be solved by adding /usr/bin/mpg123 into /etc/sudoers like:

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

and add the line

```
ALL     ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mpg123
```

than you can use in php

```
shell_exec("sudo -b /usr/bin/mpg123 YourFile")
```

good luck!

Comment: `sudo visudo` should be used instead of `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/why-do-we-need-to-use-visudo-instead-of-directly-modifying-the-sudoers-file

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of /dev/snd/ to ensure the user that PHP is running as has the correct access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path when running from PHP, as it may well be unable to find the music files with the relative path.